# Longest Increasing Subsequence

Tags: algorithms, arrays, subsequences

I got no responses on stackoverflow, so I'm asking here:

How useful is the LIS ([Longest Increasing Subsequence](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/9591)) problem in tackling other CS problems?  There are a few algorithms, using patience sorting, dynamic programming or with decision trees.  How are these used in real life -- maybe to data streams or something?

To remind you, I put in bold the longest increasing sequence

{**0**, 8, 4, 12, **2**, 10, **6**, 14, 1, **9**, 5, 13, 3, **11**, 7, **15**}.

As a bonus, is there any way to use the result that [a sequence of length mn + 1 will have an increasing subsequence of length m or a decreasing subsequence of length n](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erdos-SzekeresTheorem.html)? E.g. Our list as length 16, so there should be an increasing sequence of length 5 or decreasing sequence of length 5.  In our case *0,2,6,9,11,15*.

Also an increasing sequence of length 8 or a decreasing sequence of length 3: in our case *12,10,1*.

CF: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12458641/737051

Comment: For one application of LIS, see [this question on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288585/building-bridges-problem-how-to-apply-longest-increasing-subsequence).

Comment: @Joe The problem you're linking to sounds a bit contrived. From like a homework exercise than something that would actually come up in the real world.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus fair enough. it's still a related question