# maximal subset such as $A[i].X \lt A[j].Y$ for each $j \lt i$?

Tags: algorithms

I need to find the maximal subset $S$ of an array $A$ of length $N$ ,where each element of $A$ contains $X$ and $Y$, such that for each $0 \leq i \lt N$ , $j \lt i$ the rule is $S[i].X \lt S[j].Y$ , What would be the best approach for finding such subset of $A$ (in terms of time, knowing that $N \leq 100,000$) ?

**EDIT:**
An example to that is $A = \{(2, 15), (6, 3), (6, 11), (4, 7), (8, 5)\}$

$S$ can be $\{(6,11),(2,15),(4,7),(6,3)\}$
where each $X$ of $S$ is smaller than each $Y$ before it

Comment: Why do you want to solve this problem? Where did it come from?

Comment: If $S$ is a subset, what is $S[i]$? Is $S$ ordered? Can we choose the order?

Comment: Seems related to Problem "[Longest subsequence such that A(i).x < A(i+1).y](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12764/longest-subsequence-such-that-ai-x-ai1-y)" which however only compares consecutive elements in the subsequence.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus $S[i]$ is the $i$-th element of $S$ , $S$ can be un-ordered

Comment: So $S$ is a sequence of distinct elements from $A$? Your terminology is very confusing. Please give an example.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus yes , I'll add an example to the question ASAP

Comment: As hendric mentioned the answer in the [other](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12764/longest-subsequence-such-that-ai-x-ai1-y) question, already answers your question and is fast enough ($O(n)$).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri , The difference is that the order doesn't matter in my problem , In the other question , he wants the longest "subsequence" , while I want is the largest "subset"

Comment: So then what does $j<i$ mean? Are you allowed/required to reorder the subset when you put it into the array $S$?

Comment: @JeffE , I'm allowed to change the order of anything , as long as $S$ ends up in the maximum length and following the rules mentioned above